# Conditional expectation when conditioning on a set

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Consider two random variables $X,Y$. $Y$ has support $\mathcal{Y}\equiv \mathcal{Y}_1\cup \mathcal{Y}_2$. $X$ has support $\mathcal{X}$. $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are finite sets.

Take a function $f(X,Y)$ and a parameter $\beta$. Suppose that 
$$
E(f(X,y)-\beta)\geq 0 \text{ }\forall y\in \mathcal{Y}_1
$$

The textbook asks me to show that this implies
$$
E(f(X,Y)-\beta| Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)\geq 0
$$

I would like your help to understand

1) What is $E(f(X,Y)| Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)$? I know that $\forall y \in \mathcal{Y}_1$ 
$$
E(f(X,Y)| Y=y)\equiv \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} f(x,y)P(X=x| Y=y) 
$$
but I don't understand how $E(f(X,Y)| Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)$ is defined.

2) How to get that implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view $E\{f(X,Y)|Y=y\}$ as a special case of conditioning on a set.  $E\{f(X,Y)|Y=y\}=E\{f(X,Y)|Y\in\{y\}\}$. In general,
\begin{align}
E\{f(X,Y)|Y\in\mathcal{Y}_1\} &= \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, y\in \mathcal{Y}_1}f(x,y)P(X=x, Y=y|Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)\\
&=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, y\in \mathcal{Y}_1}f(x,y)P(X=x|Y=y)P(Y=y|Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)\\
&=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, y\in \mathcal{Y}_1}f(x,y)P(X=x
|Y=y)\frac{P(Y=y)}{P(Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)}\\
&=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, y\in \mathcal{Y}_1}f(x,y)P(X=x|Y=y)\frac{P(Y=y)}{\sum_{y\in\mathcal{Y}_1}P(Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)}.
\end{align}
Can you complete the answer now?

Comment: Thanks. In the first equality of your derivations, you write $E(f(X,Y)|Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}f(x,y)P(X=x|Y\in \mathcal{Y}_1)$. What is SMALL $y$?

Comment: Sorry! That was a mistake. Fixed it!

Comment: Thank you. This was useful (+1)! I have posted another question on conditional expectations https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254384/showing-a-claim-involving-conditional-expectations. Please help if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When faced with a random variable $X$ and an event $A$, the following may help:
$$E[X|A] = \frac{E[X1_{A}]}{P(A)}$$
where $1_{()}$ is the indicator function.
In your case replace $X$ with $f(X,Y)$ and $A$ with $\{y \in \mathcal{Y}\}$.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, I need more scholastic help, sorry, Could you add details?

Comment: Looks like the next answer has the details you seek!!