# Showing a claim involving conditional expectations

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Consider a random vector $\eta\equiv (\eta_1,...,\eta_J)$ with support $\mathbb{R}^J$.

Let $\mathcal{J}\equiv \{1,...,J\}$ and let us partition $\mathcal{J}$ into two sets, $\mathcal{J}_1$ and $\mathcal{J}_2$, with cardinalities denoted by $|\mathcal{J}_1|$ and $|\mathcal{J}_2|$.

Consider some known parameters $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_J, \beta$.

Let $\bar{\eta}$ be **a realisation** of $\eta$ (i.e., a $J\times 1$ vector of real numbers).

Assume that 
$$
\alpha_j-\beta -\bar{\eta}_j\geq 0 \hspace{1cm}\forall j \in \mathcal{J}_1
$$

**Claim to show:** 
$$
E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| j\in \mathcal{J}_1)\geq 0
$$

---

I am struggling to understand what the claim means and how it is shown. Could you help? There could be hidden conditions to add, please suggest them if you think they are implicit.

My thoughts:

**Fact 0:** How is the conditional expectation $E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| j\in \mathcal{J}_1)$ defined? The only way I can think of is by considering the sets $\mathcal{J}_1$ and $\mathcal{J}_2$ as "random". Then, we define a random variable $Q_j$ taking value $1$ if $j\in \mathcal{J}_1$ and $0$ otherwise. Hence, 
$$
E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| j\in \mathcal{J}_1)=E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| Q_j=1)\equiv \sum_{\bar{\eta}_j\in \mathbb{R}} \Big[\alpha_j -\beta-\bar{\eta}_j\Big] Pr(\eta_j=\bar{\eta}_j| Q_j=1)
$$

**Fact 1:** 
$$
\overbrace{\alpha_j-\beta -\bar{\eta}_j}^{\text{This is just a number!}}\geq 0 \hspace{1cm}\forall j \in \mathcal{J}_1
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
\overbrace{\frac{1}{|\mathcal{J}_1|}\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{J}_1} \Big[ \alpha_j-\beta -\bar{\eta}_j\Big]}^{\text{This is just a number!}}\geq 0
$$

**Fact 2:** 
$$
\text{ If $|\mathcal{J}_1|$ large and $\{\eta_j\}_{j\in \mathcal{J}_1}$ i.i.d., then }\\\frac{1}{|\mathcal{J}_1|}\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{J}_1} \Big[ \alpha_j-\beta -\eta_j\Big]\to_{a.s.} E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| Q_j=1) \\  \text{ by law of large numbers}
$$
Therefore, $\frac{1}{|\mathcal{J}_1|}\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{J}_1} \Big[ \alpha_j-\beta -\bar{\eta}_j\Big]$ is a good approximation of $E(\alpha_j -\beta-\eta_j| Q_j=1)$ when $J$ is very large. Hence, we can conclude that the claim should hold.

Is this the correct interpretation? It does not actually convince me what I wrote because if $\mathcal{J}_1$ is "random", then also $|\mathcal{J}_1|$ is random...

Comment: I'd read it as a random $j\in\mathcal{J}$ (and also random $\eta$ is given) with fixed (non-random) partition $\mathcal{J}=\mathcal{J}_1\amalg\mathcal{J}_2$.

Comment: If I follow your interpretation, what confuses me  is the use of the  index $j$ for the conditioning event, the same $j$ as the one used to define the components of $\eta$.

Comment: Following the spirit of your comment, let us imagine to create a box containing $|\mathcal{J}_1|$ balls and each ball $j$ has a label given by the number $\alpha_j-\beta-\bar{\eta}_j$. This is our sample space $\Omega$. Let us now draw a ball and record the attached label. We can represent this action by using a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \{(\alpha_j-\beta-\bar{\eta}_j)\}_{\forall j \in \mathcal{J}_1}$. Clearly, $E(X)\geq 0$. How can I go from here to the claim above?

Comment: $\bar{\eta}_j$ is a number. It does not have a distribution.

Comment: $j$ is a random variable, so $\eta_j$ and $\bar\eta_j$ are random variables too.  Now we need to argue $\mathbb{E}[(\eta_j(\omega)-\bar\eta_j) 1_A]=0$ where expectation is taken both in $\omega$ and in $j$, should be the same.  If we are taking expectation with respect to empirical distribution for $\omega$ then it is true, otherwise I don't see any reason why it should be so.

Comment: I see, thanks. where is my interpretation (in the question above) instead wrong? I'm trying to choose between my and your reading.

Comment: The only difference is whether $\mathcal{J}_1$ should be fixed or random.  So my version is a pointwise ($\mathcal{J}_1\in [J]^{\lvert\mathcal{J}_1\rvert}$) version of yours but at the cost of interpreting the expectation in empirical (or possibly some sort of Bayesian posteriors would work too), because LLN is not available when there is just one observation.  Note that $j$ is allowed to vary inside $\mathcal{J}_1$ in your Fact 2, so you already used $j$ as a random variable.